# Is it advisable to configure a URL with both post and get?

Tags: security, post, get

I have a link on my page that redirects to another page but the request is sent through POST method. Now when the user refreshes the new page the request is sent through GET method. The URL is just used to display a page. My question is, is it advisable to use both POST and GET for the same URL call or will it cause problems related to security or any other? If so please do explain how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Use `POST` if the link is executing an [unsafe action](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) (e.g. logout, change password) or it is sending sensitive data you do not want displayed in the URL (URLs are logged by default in the browser history and by many appliances, proxies and web servers). `POST` can also be used when a large amount of information is to be sent.

Otherwise use `GET`.

Comment: There is no unsafe action, will there be a problem if both POST and GET are used?

Comment: @vignesh: Not in itself, no. As long as you are not doing different permission checks for `POST` or `GET` - e.g. you might be checking they have write permission if `POST` is used, but not on your `GET` method. If not then fine.